# Return multiple rows in python function

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Am trying to print multiple rows with the return statement, but it is printing only one record.

```
def extract(self):
    data = self.oracle_conn().execute('select * from employees').fetchall()
    for row in data:
        
        return row
```

[image]

Any suggestion will be helpful to print multiple lines **without using pandas**

Comment: Use the `print(row)` to print rows.. your code will return the first row because `return` exits the function, returning the value to the caller.

Comment: I actually need to pass the return value to another function, that's the reason i need it as return value

Comment: return the data not row

Comment: data already contains all rows, just `return data`.

Comment: I tried using data, but it returns a single list of tuples and not multiple lists

Comment: If the suggestion from Luis is not sufficient, use an example to demonstrate what you are trying to do!

Answer (score 1):

```
def extract(self):
    data = self.oracle_conn().execute('select * from employees').fetchall()
    for row in data:
        yield row
```